# Notation about cardinals

Tags: set-theory, terminology, cardinals

Does a cardinal $\mathcal{k}$ such that $2^\mathcal{k}=k^+$  have any special name? I never encountered any name for this property, but I think it is possible they have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$, we sometimes say that "$\sf CH$ holds for $\kappa$". This can be denoted by $\sf CH(\kappa)$ or $\sf CH_\kappa$, although you don't see this often. Most of the time, people just write $2^\kappa=\kappa^+$.

There is no particular term for cardinals satisfying this property, and if only because we can prove that no cardinal provably satisfies that property.